# UWP to launch my application from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, uwp

I have a Windows store app I want to run (if not running) or expand (if not expanded) of another of my app written in WPF.

Through The Process.Start() I could not do. Tell me, can this be done? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To launch an UWP app from another app, you could make use of deep linking.

[Here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/22/using-cross-app-communication-to-make-apps-work-together-10-by-10/) is a great article describing exactly how to do that

In summary, you need to add a protocol declaration (essentially a URL with a custom scheme), handle the activation event and then you can launch that app by navigating to that URL from your other application.