# C# UWP To Open WPF App

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, uwp

When I try to Open an **WPF** app from my UWP App, it says it will need an app to launch the target. What do I need to do fix the following error?
[image]

My **Windows 10** machine in LTSB Version and **VS 2015** is my development environment.

Comment: May help this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37818304/1876572

Answer (score 1):

To launch an app using custom URI scheme, you first have to register the app as the URI handler in Windows Registry. This is a bit tedious, but you can see the complete [samples on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx).

If your WPF app has an installer, you can safely add the registry entries as part of the installation process. The app can also read the URI and parse the passed values as necessary.

The alternative would be to use [Windows Runtime Brokered Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps) and call the .NET Framework's `Process.Start` method. This however results in more work and it is better to avoid in case you can implement the URI activation.